# How to get iframe element button click javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i want to get the inner html contents of clicked element in iframe loaded content using javascript.

working jquery code

```
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {       
       $iframe = $(el.contentWindow.document);
       $iframe.find("body").click(function(e){
          console.log(e);   

       });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You approach will not work. use the below method to communicate the click event.

In the Child Html (**which is inside the iframe**)

```
$('body').on('click', function(){
    var type = 'bodyClick';
    var event = new CustomEvent('frameClick', { detail: type  })
    window.parent.document.dispatchEvent(event)
})
```

in Parent Html (**the html which has the iframe inserted**)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.document.addEventListener('frameClick', handleEvent, false)
    function handleEvent(e) {
      if(e.detail=="bodyClick") {
         //you can write your code here.
      }
    }
})
```